# MySQL: Update multiple columns if their value equals to

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I would like to know if there's a 'short' way (single query) to update certain columns, if their value equals to an integer.

Let's say that my table looks like this:

```
+------------+----+----+----+----+
| customerID | v0 | v1 | v2 | v3 |
+------------+----+----+----+----+
|          1 |  3 |  3 |  2 |  1 |
+------------+----+----+----+----+
```

and I would like to set all the values of integer 3 (except `customerID`) to 0 - so the query will update column `v0` and `v1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a bunch of `case` statements:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET    v0 = CASE v0 WHEN 3 THEN 0 ELSE v0 END,
       v1 = CASE v1 WHEN 3 THEN 0 ELSE v1 END,
       v2 = CASE v2 WHEN 3 THEN 0 ELSE v2 END,
       v3 = CASE v3 WHEN 3 THEN 0 ELSE v3 END
WHERE  3 IN (v0, v1, v2, v3)
```

Answer (score 1):

[Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34698036/3208640), has already mentioned one useful way, another way is using **If** statement

```
Update my_table
set v0= If(v0=3,0,v0),
    v1= If(v1=3,0,v1),
    v2= If(v2=3,0,v2),
    v3= If(v3=3,0,v3)
where 3 In (v0, v1, v2, v3)
```

here is the [DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2b488).